# knockout performance - can you bind properties if your objects are not observable?

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

We have a large nested observable array mapped though templates to create a tree view.  The list is dynamic, but there are potentially 1000+ elements in the tree.

We are having performance issues loading and searching this collection - most noticeably in IE8 and iPad. Chrome seems ok.

The elements in the collection don't actually change, so I don't think we need the 'notify' aspects of the observables, but we want to take advantage of the databinding.

Is there a way to do data-binding to objects in your viewmodel which are not observable?
Is there a way to create non-observable complex data collections without using ko.mapping.fromJS()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can totally bind properties that do not change and are not observables. It seems like you just want to map a large object to another in the same way as the mapping plugin but without creating observables. Have you considered simply using [JQuery.extend](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/)?

If you array is observable then make sure you follow the guidelines in [this excellent post](http://www.knockmeout.net/2012/04/knockoutjs-performance-gotcha.html).

I've also heard of people getting better performance by switching from native templating to third parties like jquery.tmpl (not sure if this applied to you).

**EDIT**

After further clarification in the comments. The problem was that your bindings were assuming that the properties were observables. In your template you have the follow line.

```
 <!-- ko if: IsSectionHeader() -->
```

This is executing the observable `IsSectionHeader` in order to get it's value. This is fine when IsSectionHeader is an observable because observable **are** functions. When you switch to raw model this won't work. I recommend using a tool such as firebug and checking the error console, it reported the error exactly.

Anyway, the fix was to remove the double brackets. Note, that the ko bindings can take observables with or without the brackets even if the property is observable so they weren't needed anyway.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your input. It's not so much that we want to map one object to another, but rather that we want access to the object for binding the properties to the templates rendering the tree.

Comment: @Beth - I'm confused as to what your issue is? What do you mean by "we want access to the object for binding"? If you create a plain old js object with non-observable properties and use the one way KO bindings like text, it works just fine.

Comment: In the current implementation, we get the data from codebehind variable to pull it into the aspx. When we add it to the view model using the mapping plugin e.g. viewModel.vmAvailablePages = ko.mapping.fromJS(dataAvailablePages); - all is well. But if we remove the mapping wrapper e.g. viewModel.vmAvailablePages = dataAvailablePages -then we get binding errors.

Comment: @Beth - If you mock up a jsfiddle demonstrating the issue I can probably help you. You can use this as a starting point. http://jsfiddle.net/madcapnmckay/qYmvh/

Comment: Thanks very much.  I had seen the error in the debug version - just didn't interpret it well.